# Maven not calling testng parameters

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Facing a strange problem:
When I am executing test by clicking testng.xml everything is working fine.
but executing same file by maven than its throwing me error. Why testng is not taking parameter value when running through maven??

**org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'deviceName' is required by @Configuration on method Beforetest but has not been marked @Optional or defined**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ muProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\TehnologyWork\Workspaces\TestFramework\myProject\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ muProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ muProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\TehnologyWork\Workspaces\TestFramework\myProject\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ muProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ muProject ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\TehnologyWork\Workspaces\TestFramework\myProject\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.ShoppingTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@4f8e5cde
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.383 sec <<< FAILURE!
Beforetest(test.ShoppingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.276 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'deviceName' is required by @Configuration on method Beforetest but has not been marked @Optional or defined

        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:148)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:361)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:197)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:585)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Failed tests:   Beforetest(test.ShoppingTest): (..)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.215 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-02T10:40:44+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project muProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\TehnologyWork\Workspaces\TestFramework\myProject\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My Test java file **ShoppingTest.java**:

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ShoppingTest {


        @Test
        public void test(){
                System.out.println("1111111111111");
        }

        @BeforeMethod
        @Parameters("deviceName")
        public void Beforetest(String deviceName){
                System.out.println("1111111111111");
                System.out.println(deviceName);
        }
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Suite" parallel="false">
        <test name="test name ">
                <parameter name="deviceName" value="XT1033" />
                <classes>
                        <class name="test.ShoppingTest" />
                </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**porm.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.org</groupId>
        <artifactId>muProject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>myProject</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.3</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.7</source>
                                        <target>1.7</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.18.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.18.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.5.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.7</source>
                                        <target>1.7</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </reporting>
        <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                                <version>6.9.6</version>
                        </dependency>
                </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: How you are running via `maven`? According to error it is running only one test, you are not running full suite. If you are clicking on `testng.xml` and making it run the entire suite, similarly click on `pom.xml` and make it run via maven. Run it as `Maven Test`.

Comment: Yes I am right clicking on pom.xml and running as Maven Test @mk08

Comment: Yes I also faced same issue. So I tried using my `pom.xml`, which I often use in my project. Sharing same as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully executed your code with same `java`,`testng.xml` and same package structure.
Only I did not used your given `pom.xml`. I used this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestngPOM</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestngPOM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestngPOM</name>
  <description>adding testNG xml in pom</description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <configuration>
          <forkCount>0</forkCount>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

May be this has something to do with `surefire plugin` & `testng` dependency version I used.
Give it a try.